# CR730-A-24 identification

Tags: relay, identification

Can anyone find a data sheet for what I think is a relay? It has the code cr730-a-24, 7.5A 250V on the case and I've found this picture:

[image]

Are the three circles, 3 coils in parallel? How does this circuit relate to the pin-out? In what sequence do the normally open, relay contacts close?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a relay used in PIR lamps.

[image]

<sup>*[source - P29](http://publications.theseus.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/9838/Kuusijarvi.Juho.pdf?sequence=2)*</sup>

The diagram appears to be an application where a set of three lights can be switched on by any of three switches or relays. I would guess that PR1 and PR2 are two PIR detector units at separate locations and that *wylacznik* is a manual switch.  I don't think you can deduce anything about the CR730-A-24 relay from that diagram.

Comment: Hi, but do you know the pinout of one relay?

Comment: @reggie, if you're still interested in this question determining a relay pinout is normally pretty trivial if you either have the relay or the board that requires one, but would be best as a new question.